# Regex expression for a filename in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble saving a specific string from a filename using regex.  The filename is in this format:

```
PM_IGZZZZZ_XX_YYYYMMDDHHmm_01.csv

XX can be 5, 15 or 60
ZZZZZ can be any numerical value 00000 to 99999
```

I wanna get the value IG80034 and XX. My code is:

```
String test = file.getName();
// Get IGZZZZZ
String value1 = test.replace(???,???)
// GET XX
String value21 = test.replace(???,???)
```

Anyone have any idea? thank you

Comment: Quick and Dirty - Tokenize on "_" and get elements with index 1 and 2; Also you can try crafting another method using Apache's StringUtils. Actually if your format is constant, you can substring on hardcoded index. Just avoid regex when you can ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^PM_IG(\\d{5})_(\\d{1,2})_
```

`ZZZZZ`  is in group 1
`XX` is in group 2.